# Why automatic variable will contain garbage if it is not set?

Tags: c, garbage

In  'The C programming language' third edition and on p.32 I saw those lines which make me confused:

> Because automatic variables come and go with function invocation, they
>   do not retain their values from one call to the next, and must be
>   explicitly set upon each entry. If they are not set, they will contain
>   garbage

Is it saying that for the following code, `a` will not contain garbage after the program finished its execution and if I declare `a` like this: `int a;` then `a` will contain garbage?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
        int a = 5;
        // int a;
        printf("\n\t %d", a);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't contain garbage. It is undefined what is contained. On windows it would probably be 0, but it could be flying monkey dishwashers according to the C language.

Comment: The problem is that it *often* will contain `0`, but not always. Programmers who fail to initialize their automatic variables will see that it works most of the time...which is much worse than having it fail consistently.

Comment: basically i contains garbage left by last executed program.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This explains the monkey in my room.

Comment: Are you guys drunk? Prints 5 here. Compiler: my head.

Comment: @MarounMaroun At least the dishes are getting "done".

Comment: @Igor I'm high not drunk, but I still know that OP is referring to the commented part in his code.

Comment: @Igor: I was talking about uninitialized automatic variables, not the OPs specific code.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr It will not contain data "left by last executed program" on any modern (multi-user, protected memory) operating system. That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: To be ridiculously pedantic, the correct term is "indeterminate". It will *most likely* be something other than all-bits-zero, and it may not even be a valid value for that type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the value of a not initialised variable is undefined behaviour. In practice automatic variables are allocated in processor registers or on the stack. Normally if not initialised they will get the value present in the register or memory used for the stack at the moment. So e.g. an `int` variable may contain a part of memory which was `double` variable in a function called just a moment ago. In other words the value is random.

Comment: Or, if you don't have a braindead compiler, it'll be a register. The contents of which will also be undefined...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1(void)
{
    int num1;
    printf("fun1: %i\n", num1);
}

void fun2(void)
{
    int num2 = 7;
    printf("fun2: %i\n", num2);
}

int main(void)
{ 
    fun1();
    fun2();
    fun1();

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, I get the following output:

> fun1: 0
>   fun2: 7
>   fun1: 7

As you can see, because `num1` is not initialized, it has the  value of whatever is on the stack at the time of the call.

You can visualize the stack like this during program execution like this:

```
    main     fun1     main     fun2     main     fun1     main
    [0]  SP->[0]      [0]  SP->[7]      [7]  SP->[7]      [7]
SP->[x]      [x]  SP->[x]      [x]  SP->[x]      [x]  SP->[x]

Legend: SP = Stack Pointer, x = Don't Care
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't initialize the variable before using it it will just get filled with whatever the computer had in the memory space where the variable is located, that's why it is good practice to always give them an initial value, even if it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

1. Auto variables are allocated on stack. Stack change it's size very often. Pushing on stack does not overwrite memory, but just move stack pointer. So, function frame (saved registers, local storage and local variables of function) is placed on stack instead of other frame and overlap some information.
2. Static and global variables are placed in data segment or bss segment. This segments are filled with zeros due to security reasons. Imagine, that you didn't fill this segment with zeros. As computer doesn't overwrite memory new program can get access to information of previous program that was allocated on this place.
3. There are also register variables, we ask compiler to place them in registers. But it is not guaranteed, because compiler may decide to substitute them with auto variables.

Comment: C does not specify that "Auto variables are allocated on stack".  Neither does C specify "Static and global variables are placed in data segment or bss segment.".  Many memory models exist.